# Integration test for has_one relationship failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I have a relationship between User and Organization:

```
User migration file:     t.references :organization, index: true, foreign_key: true
                         t.string :xml_file, null: false
User model file:         belongs_to :organization
Organization model file: has_one :user
```

The user model contains a variable `xml_file`, which is a file stored somewhere (haven't written that controller methods yet). I am trying to write an integration test:

```
def setup
  emptymap = fixture_file_upload('test/fixtures/empty.xml', 'application/xml', :binary)  # I have uploaded this file in the fixtures directory.
  @organization = organizations(:one)  # Which is in the organizations fixtures file.
  @user = @organization.users.build(xml_file: emptymap)
end

test "should be valid" do
  assert @user.valid?
end
```

This generates the error (referring to the `@user` line in the test):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<Organization:0x00000008a41d18>
```

If I change the @user line in `def setup` to `@user = @organization.user.build(xml_file: emptymap)` it generates the error message: `NoMethodError: undefined method`build' for nil:NilClass`. So that doesn't seem to be it, either.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `@organization.user.build` not `users`

Comment: Then it still generates the error message: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Its actually  `@organization.build_user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build` as you use it only works with collections. since you have in `User` `belongs_to :organization` and in `Organization`has one :user` you don't have a collection, you have a one-to-one relationship.

So the correct attribute is `@organization.user`

And there's a special format for one-to-one relationships... `build_(something)`

```
@organization.build_user(xml_file: emptymap)
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the original problem. The test doesn't pass yet, and it turns out to because of a model validation (if I remove it the test passes): `validate :xml_file_format` `private def xml_file_format` `errors.add(:xml_file, "File format error") unless (xml_file.match(/\.xml\z/))` `end`. You wouldn't happen to know why?

Comment: Because the file has to end with ".xml" according to that validation.

Comment: But doesn't this refer to the file "test/fixtures/empty.xml", which indeed ends with ".xml"? So shouldn't that be valid then?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the string xml_file to see what.it contains. Have you associated an uploader with it?

Comment: So far, I've only copy-pasted an empty xml file to the fixtures directory. I've set up the migration and model files. That's it. There's no controller code or anything associated to it yet (and also no associated uploader). How can I inspect the *string* xml_file in the test environment?

Comment: Or I guess that must be the problem, it's not yet converting it to a string and the model doesn't know what to do with the 'uploaded' file.